# what's the term of feeding milk to a young one by its mother animal?

Tags: word-request

We say breast feeding when a woman feeds her own human milk to her baby directly. Then,what will we say in case of four footed animals ?

Furthermore,

I want to know that as we use the name of the part of body i.e. breast (from which milk is coming out) in case of human beings, can we use the name of the part of body (from which milk is coming out i.e. abdomen) for many four footed animals in case of animals? Or will the meaning be very odd (vulgar) if we say a new term -'abdomen feeding' (for animals).

Comment: Is this even worldbuilding? Perhaps English, English Language Learners, or Biology would be more appropriate.

Comment: "Suckling", "nursing", and "breastfeeding" are all used to describe the activity (both giving and receiving, oddly). "Suckling" is usually used for animals but is sometimes used for humans. I think "breastfeeding" is only used for humans. "Nursing" is used for both.

Answer (score 5):

**Suckling.**

Both the feeding and the eating are called [suckling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suckling). It's a weird word in that it can be used as a noun (refering to the animal who is drinking the milk) or as a verb (referring to either the act of feeding or the act of eating).

Comment: We say breast feeding for human being.what is the term that can be used like breast feeding in case of a cow?

Comment: @MANILALAHEIBAM **Suckling**.

Comment: Also "nursing" which is used for both humans and animals

Comment: Question edited. Kindly review